# Partitioning $\mathbb{R}$ for given functions.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $f,g$ be two real valued bounded measurable functions. I'd like to construct two Borel sets $O_1$ and $O_2$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that they partition $\mathbb{R}$ ($O_1 \cup O_2= \mathbb{R}$ and $O_1 \cap O_2= \phi$) and satisfy $ (supp(f-g)^{+})^c \subset O_1$ and   $ (supp(f-g)^{-})^c \subset O_2$. Where $f^\pm$ denotes the positive and negative part of $f$ respectively and supp stands for the support of the function.

If $f,g$ were continuous then we could have chosen $O_1=supp(f-g)^{-}$ and $O_2=supp(f-g)^{+}$. As in this case both $O_1$ and $O_2$ will be Borel sets. How do we choose $O_1,O_2$ for any bounded function?

Comment: Aren't $O_1,O_2$ Borel as well in the case $f,g$ are only measurable?

Comment: they will be measurable, not necessary Borel.

Comment: So in your case $f,g$ are Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: Yes they are, sorry for the confusion if any.